# Add or to an if condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, or-operator

I have this if condition:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['altgeraet'])) {
    $Altgeraet = 'OK';
} else {
    $Altgeraet = 'NOK';
}
```

And I want when in the SQL Table `Host_alt` the value "KeinAlterHost" is the

```
$Altgeraet = 'OK'
```

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['altgeraet']) 
        OR ($resultarray['Hostname_alt'] == "KeinAlterHost")) {
    $Altgeraet = 'OK';
} else {
    $Altgeraet = 'NOK';
}
```

So is this setup right? I used the `array_key_exists`

```
if ((isset($_REQUEST['altgeraet']) OR (array_key_exists('KeinAlterHost',$resultarray['Hostname_alt'])) {
        $Altgeraet = 'OK';
        } else {
        $Altgeraet = 'NOK';
        }
```

Comment: Sometimes `===` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need an pipeline for OR

So the code will be this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['altgeraet']) || ($resultarray['Hostname_alt'] == "KeinAlterHost"))
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien, you guys says so, so it looks like it's OR == true ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The isset isn't quit right...

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['altgeraet']) OR ($resultarray['Hostname_alt'] == "KeinAlterHost")) {
    $Altgeraet = 'OK';
} else {
    $Altgeraet = 'NOK';
}
```

You need to quit it earlyer:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['altgeraet']) OR ($resultarray['Hostname_alt'] == "KeinAlterHost")) {
    $Altgeraet = 'OK';
} else {
    $Altgeraet = 'NOK';
}
```

Because it checks if the request isset, and the hostname isset at you're old code. by the new one, it checks if the request isset, if not check if hostname == keinalterhost and then do the stuff...

Comment: still a white page what do you guys mean with case sensitive?

Comment: @user1489323 names are case sensitive. so KeinAlterHost is something difrent then keinalterhost. with == it shouldn't be always an trouble, but with === it strictly checks on that.

Comment: @user1489323 case sensitive means helloworld != HeLloWOrLD

Comment: @TWCrap Your if condition is wrong, take out closing parentheses before **OR**

Comment: @Mr.Alien where do i have to insert array_key_exists im not that good with php

Comment: @Mr.Alien didnt work i will check my whole code maybe somewhere else is an error